# Problemas ao debugar no vscode os Breakpoints ficam desativados

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, debug

Pessoal estou com um problema ao iniciar o debug no vscode (F5) os Breakpoints ficam desativados, assim não efetuando as paradas nos locais escolhidos.
Já alterei o "webRoot" com barra ou sem no launch.json, conferma abaixo.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Iniciar o Chrome em relação a localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:4200",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/MY-PROJECT"
        }
    ]
}
```

Alterei também no Tsconfig.json o sourceMap para true e depois false para ver se dava certo e nada.

Gostaria de saber se alguém já passou por isso e se tem uma solução e porque isso acontece.

[configuração do launch.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2t6I.png)

Antes de iniciar o debug.

[Antes de iniciar o debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZpLB.png)

Ao iniciar o Debug.

[Ao iniciar o debug onde os breakpoits ficam desativados](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTUls.png)

Answer (score 0):

Esse item foi resolvido da seguinte maneira adicionando esse item "start": "ng serve --host=127.0.0.1" no package.json. Agora estou tentando entender o que ocorre o erro Unexpected 503 response from http://127.0.0.1:4200/runtime.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4200

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).